# Angular 2: UI binding with large rows of data

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I have a list of items, which is an array[]. I did the binding of this array with my template to show the list of items in UI. When user clicks on the tab. Items rows with data should be visible.

The size of the data is around 10k rows which is quite big. It took around 2 to 3 seconds to display the data in UI after click. I wanted to improve this time to 1 sec or may be 0 sec. How i can achieve the performance level to show the list of 10k rows instantly.

**Please Note:** I already have the data in array, before clicking on the tab.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: Though we should show all the heavy data..but what you carry to server may be the changes of a certain column(s) data. While showing the data - just do one way binding as{{data.items}} and also keep another list of data which should contain only tracked columns. For those columns data, two way binding should be used, so that it would optimize necessary columns to be tracked.

Comment: I am doing similar application, two-way binding is discouraged in the experience...so I am relying on eventEmitters. For example, if list of checkboxes in grid to be carried their value to server, exposing a single event on a (grid) component for any checkbox checked, which would return Id, and value of checked, would suffice to update the server instead of two-way binding.